# Mathjax rendering fails

Tags: javascript, mathjax

For the well rendered sentences, I copy/paste and editted with the sentences. Original sentence and the editted one are not rendered at all like an entanglement in quantum physics.

Is there a way make the sentences rendered?

Not rendered sentence in second image is editted sentences after copy/paste

[image]

[image]